# Remove "!important" coming from bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I want to override `.text-primary` with a color of my choice.

So in my override file, I defined it like:

```
@include text-emphasis-variant(".text-primary",$brand-primary, true);
```

The `text-emphasis-variant` is a mixin from Bootstrap 4 that is defined in such a way that the `color` property is marked as `!important`.  So the generated css file is as follows:

```
.text-primary {
  color: #007bff !important; }

a.text-primary:hover, a.text-primary:focus {
  color: #0056b3 !important; }

.text-primary {
  color: #0078D2 !important; }

a.text-primary:hover, a.text-primary:focus {
  color: #004c86 !important; }
```

Now, I want to use the `text-primary` class inside another class:

```
<div class="customRow">
    <span class="text-primary"> Testing </span>
</div>
```

And I have another override like:

```
.customRow>span {
    color: #555
}
```

The problem here is that it is not taking the color `#555` since the color in `text-primary` is marked as `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your SCSS file.

```scss
$enable-important-utilities: false;
```

source https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#importance

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently working on a project that i overrided the bootstrap 5 by following this tutorial hope it can help you too .
if you are using Bootstrap 5 The right way to override $theme-colors is to by doing this

```
// First override some or all individual color variables
$primary: #25408f;
$secondary: #8f5325;
$success: #3e8d63;
$info: #13101c;
$warning: #945707;
$danger: #d62518;
$light: #f8f9fa;
$dark: #343a40;

// Then add them to your custom theme-colors map, together with any additional colors you might need
$theme-colors: (
  primary: $primary,
  secondary: $secondary,
  success: $success,
  info: $info,
  warning: $warning,
  danger: $danger,
  light: $light,
  dark: $dark,
  // add any additional color below
);
```

for more information see this [link](https://blog.assistancy.be/blog/bootstrap-5-override-theme-colors-sass)